# How to add a space in the code section?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I have seen [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#need-more-detail), but I couldn't find how to add a space to the code snippet.

For example, this :

```
1
 2
 3
```

Should look like this (1 space in the last line) :
1
_2
_3
_

So, how do I add a line with only spaces in the code?

Comment: Why do you need a blank line at the end?

Comment: @Straitjacket Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345649/how-to-change-delimiters-position

Comment: Oh, output formatting...right. Missed that one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that using the HTML tags `<pre><code>` instead of indentation by 4 spaces:

```
<pre><code>1
 2
 3
&nbsp;</code></pre>
```

will give

```
1
 2
 3
```

Since you're using this for formatting *output*, you probably don't want syntax highlighting anyway; then you should omit the `<code>` and `</code>` tags. (Kinda obvious: don't use 'em if it ain't code.)

Answer (score 3):

Enter a non-breaking space - not the `&nbsp;` version, the proper unicode version - after four normal spaces and the result is:

```
1
 2
 3
```

On Windows you enter this with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + ( <kbd>Keypad 0</kbd>, <kbd>Keypad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Keypad 6</kbd>, <kbd>Keypad 0</kbd> ).

On Mac OS X you enter this with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to enter it directly on Linux...

Comment: First I thought of this, too, but it has the disadvantage that if people copy-and-paste that code, they may catch the unicode space without noticing.

Comment: @Hendrik, hmmm true. But I guess that'll teach them to not copy-paste random code without checking it thoroughly?

Comment: Your workaround is still good to keep in mind, but the nasty thing about the unicode space is that even with thorough checking it's hard to discover.